# Translation of "I find it interesting ..."

Tags: traduction, subjonctif

"I find it interesting that a suit is required for this event."

> Je trouve intéressant qu'un costume soit requis pour cet événement.

Is this translation correct? Should we use "Je **le** trouve ..." instead of "Je trouve ..."? And is the use of subjunctive here appropriate? (I think it is appropriate since it's an opinion.)

Comment: Translation is correct. Some might say "Je trouve *ça* intéressant ..." but definitely not "Je *le* trouve ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is correct, and the subjunctive usage is appropriate too.

You can use 'ça' or 'cela' as you use 'it':

> Un costume est requis pour cet événement. (*A costume is required for this event.*)
>
> > Je trouve ça/cela intéressant.

You could only use 'le' (or 'la') in case you're talking about a person:

> Qu'as-tu pensé de l'invité(e) ? (*What did you think of the guest?*)
>
> > Je le/la trouve intéressant(e).